# How to set up different environments of Wso2 AM on a single localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, wso2, ubuntu-18.04, wso2-api-manager, environment

somehow it is possible to run **different environments** in Wso2 API Manager like development, test and production environments on a single machine as this video shows it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wd3ubjxEM_I

I have tried it with two docker images of Wso2 called wso2/wso2am and did a offset to their ports so first runs on port 9444 and the second on 9445. I have also a local installation of Wso2 AM on my local machine on port 9443.

But they do not run independantly. When I log in myself as admin on one port, it automatically logs me out of other ports.

So how do I set up independant different environments on my local machine as in that YouTube Video? I am using the **Wso2 API Manager 3.1.0 Version** and **Ubuntu 18.04** OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same browser as all deployments use the same cookies for the UI. Use 3 different browsers or 3 browser profiles.

Comment: Could you not better alternatively connect to the container's own IP adres (provided it is available to the user)? This would circumvent having to install a second browser or use the incognito mode altogether?

Comment: Yes, that should work too. And different hostnames should work too.

Comment: Using a different browser and the incognito mode worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @Bee; Another good suggestion. Did not even think of that one.